# Call a method of a component which is inside of <ng-content> within its parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, transclusion

First of all here is the [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4lyKhsH1GOKcnh0964sy)

Essentially, I have a tab control that is dynamic. There will be any number of tabs, each of which will contain a component that inherits from this 'Delay-load' component. The functionality I wish to achieve is that when a user clicks on the tab, it will then call 'loadData' from within whichever component is contained within the tab.

I have tried to access the child component with @ViewChild or @ContentChild but nothing I try seems to work.

The template of the tab is:

```
<div [hidden]="!active" class="pane">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

And on the setter of the property 'active' within the tab component, I wish to call the .loadData() method of whatever component is held within the  element. Is this achievable?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YA3WFkE1L3WJNyjspeWr?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui this helped immensely, if you would like to submit an answer (with a small description) I will mark it as the solution! :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if(this.component) {
      this.component.loadData();
    }
  }

  @ContentChild(DelayLoadComponent) component: DelayLoadComponent;
```

but it doesn't lazy load the component.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/iWeR08durojMeNf1voui?p=preview)

Perhaps you want to add an `*ngIf` that only adds the component to the DOM when the tab is active.

Comment: unfortunately I am looking to lazy load the component!

Comment: But the problem is not caused by lazy loading. Your application doesn't lazy load the component.

Comment: But that is what I am trying to achieve by asking this question? I know it doesn't lazy load the component - that's why I am here! :)

Comment: Your whole question doesn't contain `lazy` once ;-) There are questions and answers how to lazy load components without the router. You can also use `*ngIf` if you only want the component to be added to the DOM when visible. Lazy loading is loading the component from a different (different from the initial application code file) from the server.